# Identify duplicate Records Based On Different Status in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the data set as below:

```
EMP_NAME   MGRNAME    STATUS    MODIFIED_DATE 
---------------------------------------------------
Amy        John       ACTIVE    01/15/2012 00:00:00 
Amy        Ken        INSERVICE 06/08/2000 00:00:00 
Amy        Tom        INACTIVE  04/02/2010 00:00:00 
Ron        David      ACTIVE    01/15/2008 00:00:00 
Keith      Jack       INACTIVE  08/10/2005 00:00:00 
Keith      Cat        INACTIVE  04/30/2008 00:00:00 
Keith      Ken        INACTIVE  02/04/2010 00:00:00
Mary       Stephen    INACTIVE  10/18/2010 00:00:00
```

Now, i should identify the duplicate rows based on the below conditions:

- If an Emp has 1 Mgr tagged, then we should not consider the same. 
  Ex:- Ron, Mary
- If an Emp has been tagged to multiple Managers, then we need to check
  if he is tagged to any of the manager as `ACTIVE` , then we should
  not consider the same. Fetch those records whose status is `<>
  ACTIVE` for that Emp. Ex:- For Amy, we should exclude the record with
  `ACTIVE` status. We should fetch the records with `INSERVICE` and
  `INACTIVE`
- If an Emp has been tagged to multiple Managers, but he is in INACTIVE status with all of them, then leave the max(`MODIFIED_DATE`) record and fetch the remaining records
  Ex:- For Keith, as both the Mgr records Status is INACTIVE, fetch the (`MODIFIED_DATE`) records which are `08/10/2005 00:00:00` and `04/30/2008 00:00:00`

The final output should look like below:

```
EMP_NAME   MGRNAME     STATUS      MODIFIED_DATE 
------------------------------------------------------
Amy        Ken         INSERVICE   06/08/2000 00:00:00 
Amy        Tom         INACTIVE    04/02/2010 00:00:00 
Keith      Jack        INACTIVE    08/10/2005 00:00:00 
Keith      Cat         INACTIVE    04/30/2008 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME ,  MGRNAME ,   STATUS  ,  MODIFIED_DATE
FROM (
SELECT your_table.*,
rank() over (partition BY EMP_NAME ORDER BY decode(STATUS,'ACTIVE', to_date('31129999', 'ddmmyyyy'), MODIFIED_DATE) DESC ) r FROM your_table
) t
WHERE r > 1
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c106b/7) is a fiddle